# How to run recurring ActiveJob with whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I need run recurring jobs in rails 4.2 application. I install whenever gem.

I create ActiveJob

```
class Analytics::CalculateAllJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    orgs = Org.all
    orgs.each do |org|
      org.departments
      Rails.logger.info "Scheduled a job to calculate Analytics"
    end
  end
end
```

And cron job in shedule.rb i add

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "Analytics::CalculateAllJob"
end
```

Run command whenever -i. He write changes to crontab
I run cron command from command line:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/www/myproject && bin/rails runner -e development '\''Analytics::CalculateAllJob'\'' >> /home/www/myproject/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

and get

```
/home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Analytics::CalculateAllJob (NameError)
from /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `eval'
from /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
from /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `runner'
from /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails420/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/www/myproject/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My error is wroing class name call.

Working code:

app/jobs/analytics/calculate_all.rb

```
class Analytics::CalculateAll < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(*args)
    ...
  end
end
```

config/shedule.rb

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "Analytics::CalculateAll.perform_later"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of job before calling `perform`.

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "Analytics::CalculateAll.new.perform_later"
end
```